# How to update the Preferences Object in QBO (using the quickbooks-ruby gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks-online

this is regarding the amazing *quickbooks-ruby* gem.
I noticed from the docs that Updating the **Preferences** object isn't implemented yet.

Is there an alternate way to update the **Preferences** Object?

Situation:
For my rSpec tests, I need to be able to set the preferences to something and THEN run some tests, then update the preferences again before running other tests.

Specifically, I'm looking to update the class tracking preferences.

Updating for most other entities (Customers, Invoices, Esitmates, etc are implemented) it's just Preferences that aren't implemented yet, so I'm kinda stuck.

Really appreciate the help! Thanks!